# I have a setInterval function that graphs.

Tags: javascript, angularjs, d3.js, graph, chart.js

However I want to stop the setInterval function without having the graph disappear? The graph dissappears or at least the last 7 points plotted when the setInterval stops. What should I do? Thank you in advance!

`

```
var graphingID = setInterval(function(){
  if (itertn == char.length){
    clearInterval(graphingID);
   }
  itertn++;
   //Add two random numbers for each dataset
  myLiveChart.addData([char[itertn], char[itertn]], ++latestLabel);
  // Remove the first point so we dont just add values forever 
  //updateDaw();
  myLiveChart.removeData(2);
}, 50);
```

`

Answer (score 0):

Something like this maybe?

```
var graphingID = setInterval(function(){
  if (itertn == char.length){// is it time to stop? if yes clear interval
     clearInterval(graphingID);
   }
  else{// if not, go on as usual

      itertn++;
       //Add two random numbers for each dataset
      myLiveChart.addData([char[itertn], char[itertn]], ++latestLabel);
      // Remove the first point so we dont just add values forever 
      //updateDaw();
      myLiveChart.removeData(2);
 }
}, 50);
```

Answer (score 0):

Don't continue when clearing:

```
if (itertn == char.length){ clearInterval(graphingID); return; }
```